# WPF ListBox does not select after PreviewMouseButton event

Tags: wpf, listbox, selection

I am using PreviewMouseButton event to validate if an Item can be selected since I want the validation to happen only when the User Manually selects and not automatically.

As part of the Validation, I show MessageBox to confirm if the User really wants to change the Selection. Once the User says, "Yes", I should let the Selection happen, otherwise, Selection should not happen.

The problem is, even after I Pick "Yes", on the MessageBox confirmation, its not letting me Select the Item.

Could you please let me know what am I missing?

```
    private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!ParentViewModel.CanChangeList())
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }


    public bool CanChangeTree()
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            MessageBoxResult objResult = MessageBox.Show("Are You sure You want to change?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (objResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                return true;
            }else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What causes this problem is displaying the message box (though I'm not sure why is that).

If you want to stick to the message box, you'll need to retrieve the ListBoxItem that is being clicked before you display the message; and then, if allowed, set the selected item yourself.